# What is the recommended way for typesetting the Fredkin gate in quantikz?

Tags: quantikz

The obvious thing to try was

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
  & \ctrl{1} & \qw \\
  & \swap{1} & \qw \\
  & \targX{} & \qw
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

but this leaves a little unwanted space in the vertical wire:

[image]

This can be fixed by replacing `\ctrl{1}` by `\ctrl{2}`, but the lower vertical wire then looks just slightly thicker than the upper. (It's pretty good, though.) Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. I have done a zoom out and I have not seen the lower vertical wire slightly thicker than the upper.

Comment: @Sebastiano It is nitpicking, but I can also see where the wire from the control bit ends under the swap wire. A zoom out does the trick.

Comment: I have put \ctrl{3} but I have found an error :-(. Can you see, please, if you see the lower vertical wire slightly thicker than the upper?

Comment: @Sebastiano It gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using this work around:

```
    \begin{quantikz}
    & \ctrl{2} & \qw \\
    & \targX{} & \qw \\
    & \swap{-1} & \qw 
    \end{quantikz}
```

The `\ctrl{2}` passes over the `\targX{}` to connect with `\swap{-1}`:

[image: fredkin gate]